# Depreciation warning when using Compass with Zurb Foundation

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, bower

I'm new to bower/git/nodejs and using the SCSS from a css framework. Previously I would just download the framework CSS and just include it in my website. Then write scss and include that as a separate file.

I followed the directions on foundations site: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

I'm getting the following warnings which I imagine can't be good. I have sass 3.3 installed.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

But, as it's a warning not an error (for now!)
you can add

```
disable_warnings = true
```

to your config.rb.

I expect foundation will update that stuff before it becomes completely deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of Sass typically roll out backwards incompatible changes in 2 stages.  First they will release a version that warns you that the feature you're using is not going to work in a future version but it still works in *this* version.  Then they'll release a version where the feature is changed/removed.

In this case, manipulating global variables is changing.  This is perfectly valid in 3.2, but gives deprecated warnings in 3.3:

```
$foo: blue;

.foo {
    $foo: red;
}
```

It still works, though.  To properly do the same thing in 3.3 (or to silence the warnings), the code should be written like this:

```
$foo: blue;

.foo {
    $foo: red !global;
}
```

The addition of the `!global` flag makes the code incompatible with 3.2, which is all the warning is telling you.

Since this is a 3rd party library, I would recommend either ignoring it (though I suppose you're getting a *lot* of these warnings every time it compiles) or downgrading to 3.2 until the library has been updated to be compatible with 3.3.